# Flutter InputDecoration - how to position the label over the border?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

I have flutter app with text field. I need to position the label above the borders like in this picture.

[image]

I have two options:

1.write this completely as a new widget

2.use TextFormField + InputDecoration

I tried the second way, this is my code:

```
      TextFormField(
      controller: _controller,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
                     border: OutlineInputBorder(

            borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero,
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: AppColors.borderColor, width: 1.0),
          ),
          
          floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
          labelText: widget.hint
      ));
```

But I am unable to achieve the desired result.
Is this possible or only option 1?

Comment: why don't you just add another `text` widget above your `TextFormField`, it's much more painless in that way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd prefer writing this completely as a new widget like

```
Column(
    children:[
     Text('label'),
     TextFormField(//.....),
 ],
),
```